# How to combine a job dependency with a start time

Tags: autosys

How do I combine a job dependency on another job with a 'must start' time?
e.g. my Job_A is dependent on completion of Job_B but I need to override this dependency if the time 3:00AM. Job_B normally completes well before that time but I need to make sure Job_A starts at a preset hour in case of unexpected delays in Job_B.

Thanks!
Lenny.

Answer (score 1):

Given your description I don't see the need for the dependency between the two jobs. In that case you can easily remove the `Conditions` attribute and simply add `start_time` with the exact hour you want it to kick off.